# InAppBrowser comes back to the plugin list after build

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I run `cordova plugin list` I see the list of plugins installed, so I want to remove `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.1 "InAppBrowser"`. To remove the `InAppBrowser` I do `sudo cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`. If I run `cordova plugin list` again `InAppBrowser` is gone from the list.

When I run `sudo ionic build ios`, after successful build. I run `cordova plugin list`, I see `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.1 "InAppBrowser"` in the list again.

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` plugin still there on your `config.xml` file.So try as shown below.i.e. use `--save`

> sudo cordova plugin list
>
> sudo cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save
>
> sudo cordova plugin list